# $\frac{1}{z^2-5z+4}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{n=\infty}a_nz^n$. Find $a_{-10}$ and $a_{10}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, laurent-series

Here is the question:  By Laurent expansions, there exist constants $a_n$ such that for $1<|z|<4$, $\frac{1}{z^2-5z+4}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{n=\infty}a_nz^n$.  Find $a_{-10}$ and $a_{10}$.

My idea:

Using partial fraction decomposition, we find that $\frac{1}{z^2-5z+4}=\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{z-4}-\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{z-1}$.  Using Laurent expansions, we know that $\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{z-4}=\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{-1-\frac{1}{4}z}=-\frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{4^{n+1}z^n}$, and that $\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{z-1}=-\frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z^n}$.  Now, I am sort of stuck on where to go from here.  I feel like I've done the majority of the problem, but is it really just a matter of playing with indices now?  Moreover, I should ask if I made any mistakes, and if there is anything that ought to be considered for the rest of the problem.  Furthermore, just out of curiosity, I was wondering if there is any way to maybe do this simply through integration?  Any thoughts, suggestions, tips, etc. are greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in the right direction. However, since you are working in $1<|z|<4$, so for
$$\underbrace{\frac{1}{z-1}=\frac{1}{z\left(1-\frac{1}{z}\right)}}_{\because \, \left|\frac{1}{z}\right|<1}=\frac{1}{z}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z^n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z^{n+1}}.$$
And
$$\underbrace{\frac{1}{z-4}=\frac{1}{4\left(\frac{z}{4}-1\right)}}_{\because \,\left|\frac{z}{4}\right|<1}=\frac{-1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{z}{4}\right)^n=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{4^{n+1}}$$
Now you can have
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{z^2-5z+4}&=\frac{1}{3}\left[\frac{1}{z-4}-\frac{1}{z-1}\right]\\
&=\frac{-1}{3}\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{4^{n+1}}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z^{n+1}}\right]
\end{align*}
Observe that the first series will give all non-negative powers, whereas the second series will give the negative powers.

For example, $a_{-10}=\frac{-1}{3}$.

Comment: Ah, okay, so then $a_{10}=\frac{-1}{3(4)^{11}}$, right?

Comment: @User7238 Yes that's right.